# nginx alias domains different scripts

Tags: nginx

I want to handle multiple domains with multiple php apps and config files, but i would to handle it in nginx, not in php application.

First question is about performance when 1000 domains are alias in nginx versus 1000 domains are separate. What is better?

Another question is about how can i have some configuration file for domains by domain and to trigger different php scripts by parameter

for example:

```
domain1.com 
   app: Wordpress 

domain2.com
    app: Drupal
```

and then in nginx .php directive i would have:

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ /{app}/index.php?$args;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be exactly what you are looking for:

```
http {
        ...

        # custom log format to include the domain
        log_format main '$remote_addr - $host [$time_local] '
          '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
          '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

        map $host $app {
                default                "wordpress";
                "~domain.com"          "drupal";
                "~blog.other.com"      "wordpress";
                "~shop.store.com"      "magento";
        }
}

server {
        server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$; # expects site.com folder and accepts both www and non-www
        root /home/www/sites/$domain/$app;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host; # normally you would get the server_name regex
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=$document_root:/tmp/:/usr/share/php"
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        }
}
```